# Custom project template for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 not showing in "Add New Project ..."

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates

Downloaded a cutom WAP template, and placed is in the

`Y:\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\Web` folder.

ran:

```
devenv /setup
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Custom template not showing up under "My Templates" when creating a new C# Web project, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749979/visual-studio-2008-how-to-install-an-item-template/750025#750025